# GCC ERROR IN CPanel Terminal Trying to Install Pillow

Tags: django, gcc, terminal, python-imaging-library, cpanel

Please I need help, I am trying to host a Django Project in Cpanel.
I have created a Python App (Python 3.8.6)
Launched the Virtualenv on Terminal and install django according to my project version
(Django 3.2.6)

Now Trying to install Dependencies such as Pillow and Mysqlclient, I keep getting the below error.

```
unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-build-hrzlinrf/pillow -I/home/westhfef/virtualenv/humanities/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmorph.o
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have tried everything I can, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have gcc installed. The solution is to install gcc.

Answer (score -1):

Try pip install pillow==8.0.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Downgrading to pillow==8.0.0. fix the issue